# Where Does CommunityToolkit.Mvvm Put Source Generated Files

Tags: wpf, mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm schooling up on the latest MVVM stuff and followed a tutorial which displayed a place in the IDE where the generated cs files were available (under Dependencies > Analysers in Solution Explorer).

I cannot see any files there. And if I search the file system where my project is, there are no source-generated cs files.

The ViewModel which I created (a partial class) inherits from `ObservableObject` and seems to work. But I can't find any of the generated code.

Has it moved?

Thanks

Comment: OK. I understand why now. I had to decorate the property in my VM with the `ObservableProperty` attribute and make some handlers partial methods. Will answer my own question as soon as I can.